# Blocked a frame with origin how to fix

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

Blocked a frame with origin `https://xxxx` from accessing a frame with origin `https://xxx`. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I need this setup to work, and I have access to both of the domains (2 different domains).

How can I get rid of this?

I tried putting `php-header` on the page, where the `iframe` are placed:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://domain_the_iframe_is_placed");
```

And also in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

What can I do?

This is the iframe page, which is on another domain (y.com), but placed on x.com

```
  parent.document.getElementById('accoxxation').value='<?=$_POST['account_verification']?>';
  parent.document.getElementById('accxx').value='<?=$_POST['account_number']?>';
  parent.document.getElementById('accxxonth').value='<?=$_POST['account_month']?>';
  parent.document.getElementById('accxxxr').value='<?=$_POST['account_year']?>';

  parent.document.getElementById('gatewayProcessor').submit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allow-origin will allow server request known as CORS, not inter-frame connections. Try communicating with window messagging, which is designed for that purpose.
Example:

Parent:

```
myFrame.contentWindow
        .postMessage("STRING", myFrame.src);
```

myFrame:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    // Security: Validate message origin
    if (event.origin !== myVerifiedOrigin) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(event.data);
});
```

Comment: What have addEventListener to do with the example i am giving? Can you please give me a example of what you mean?

Comment: It should be reverse. Comminicating from the iFrame on the different domain to my side (parent.window)

Comment: Thanks, have accepted your answer and posted solution.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing frames from other origin is forbidden. You can change it in the depths of browser settings. I don't think it's a good idea. It's security problem. If you have control of both sources you can use postMessage to communicate throw frames.

[Tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage)

Answer (score 0):

by default you cannot /should not do this ,but according to this site

http://javascript.info/cross-window-communication

here’s a small exclusion in the “Same Origin” policy.

If windows share the same second-level domain, for instance john.site.com, peter.site.com and site.com (so that theyr common second-level domain is site.com), they can be treated as coming from the “same origin”.

To make it work, all such pages (including the one from site.com) should run the code:

```
document.domain = 'site.com';
```

That’s all. Now they can interact without limitations. Again, that’s only possible for pages with the same second-level domain.